# WP7 how to disable swiping when there is only one panorama item

Tags: windows-phone-7, swipe, panorama-control, disabled-control

I start a very basic Panorama application in Windows Phone 7. In that page is a `Panorama` control which has only 1 `PanoramaItem`.

The problem is that user can swipe this panorama. I want to disable this behavior, how to do that ?

P/S: I see that `Pivot` control does not suffer from this behavior

Comment: That's not what panorama was designed for - unless you plan to add other pano items later I'd use a different container and copy the heading style of the panorama.

Comment: Ah, because the number of panorama items in my app can vary. In case it is 1, user can swipe it which is not good. My solution is to set its IsEnable to false. But is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that setting panorama control 's `IsEnabled` to false can solve my problem

```
panorama.IsEnabled = false;
```